# remove windows 7 dual boot with ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, grub

I want to uninstall win7 from my linux dual boot system and also want to remove booting option so that after removing windows it should automatically boot my ubuntu .
So what step should I follow to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

1. Make sure all your data is backed up.
2. Are you absolutely sure there isn't any data you need on the Windows partition?
3. Boot from an Ubuntu live CD/USB and run GParted (System / Administration / Partition Editor). Remove the Windows partition and resize the Linux partition to use the whole drive.
4. Reboot into Linux and run `sudo update-grub`.

Long answer: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows